# C# UWP Login website using cookies

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, httpclient, webclient

I'm trying to convert a WPF application to UWP but am struggeling on how to get the conenction to work.

The WPF application connects to a website, get cookies, read a token from html and then post data to login.

In WPF I had this class:

```
// CookieAwareWebClient.cs
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public string Method;
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0";
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = true;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate |
                                                                 DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            if (Method == "POST")
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }

        }
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        if (setCookieHeader != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (setCookieHeader != null)
                {
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
                    this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

,that is used like this:

```
// Program.cs
// ...
CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);
string response = client.DownloadString("LINK TO WEBSITE TO GET COOKIES");

// Get the csrf token from response html
var tokenValue = Regex.Match(response, "name='csrf_token' 
value='(.+?)'").Groups[1].Value;

// Prepare values to send
string token = $"csrf_token={tokenValue}&";
string email = $"email={email}&";
string password = $"password={password}&";
string rememberme = $"rememberme=on&";
string submit = $"submit=Login";

string postData = token + email + password + rememberme + submit;

client.Method = "POST";
response = client.UploadString("LINK TO LOGIN ACTION", postData);
```

This works flawless in WPF. How can I achieve someting like this in UWP?
I tried using HttpClient, but I either get bad response, javascript doesnt load, or I can't read the response.

So far, I tried to just connect to the normal site and read the html, to get the token. But I get a response error.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("UserAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("KeepAlive", "true");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("ServicePoint.Expect100Continue", "false");


var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("LINK"));

// ERROR => System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 503 ()."
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Show what you tried with HttpClient, what error(s) if any and the desired behavior in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `CookieContainer` to the handler in order to be able to access the cookies return from the request

```
//have a cookie container before making the request
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() {
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    CookieContainer = cookies,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
};

//Handle TLS protocols (https)
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("UserAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("KeepAlive", "true");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("ServicePoint.Expect100Continue", "false");

var uri = new Uri("Link");
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// Get the csrf token from response html
var tokenValue = Regex.Match(html, "name='csrf_token' value='(.+?)'").Groups[1].Value;


//...Prepare values to send
```

Comment: I extract the csrf from the html code. I can't get the html code because if I do "string html = client.GetStringAsync(uri);" I get an error that the response if not 503 code.

Comment: @er4zox I do not understand your comment. You can get the html from the content of the response.

Comment: @er4zox 503 also indicates that the issue is with the server you are calling, not your client.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong. When I use the wpf code it works perfectly. When I read the html I only get the cloudflare page instead of the real page.

Comment: @er4zox is the link being called `http` or `https`?

Comment: The link is called by https